# design pattern - many simple receivers vs one complex reciever

Tags: android, design-patterns, textview, broadcastreceiver, performance

I have an android app which contains alot of TextViews which display incoming data of different types (think speed, direction, temperature, levels...). However only a handful are visible on any one screen.

So my question is: 
What is the lightest implementation? should i have one broadcast receiver (to unpack the incoming data and update the various Textviews as appropriate - complex) or have each TV register its own receiver and update itself as appropriate - simple.

I am not sure how much overhead all the receivers have. For now I have implemented as the second option above as it nicely encapsulates the functionality, however i notice that receivers for off screen views are still firing and there is no onPause/onResume methods for Views so cant register/unregister the receivers. Responsiveness is important so I want to keep the app as light as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the logik different for each event type received?

Comment: The only difference between the TVs is which element they display. So each has a receiver which fires and unpacks the data to see if it matches the attribute of the TV. If so, the TV text is set appropriately.  The attribute for each TV is set at design time. Also the TVs are in fragments within a single Activity. So as user changes the displayed fragment, the contained TVs remain instantiated.